# How to merge 2 types into 1 type in 1 index or migrate into new index with 1 type

Tags: elasticsearch

**My problem:**

I have an ElastichSearch index. The mapping is as below.

As you can see, I have 2 index type: TypeA and TypeB having the same mapping (properties).

Now I want to merge them into 1 type, let's call TypeC.

How can I perform that?

```
{
  "my_index" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "TypeA" : {
        "properties" : {
          "autoid" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "database" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "database_version" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "error_message" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "failure_date" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
          },
          "id_sequence" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "id_test" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "operator" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "part_number" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "read_value" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "serial_number" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "site" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "test_software_version" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "test_station" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "test_type" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "timestamp" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
          },
          "transaction_date" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
          },
          "waited_value" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "TypeB" : {
        "properties" : {
          "autoid" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "database" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "database_version" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "error_message" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "failure_date" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
          },
          "id_sequence" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "id_test" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "operator" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "part_number" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "read_value" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "serial_number" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "site" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "test_software_version" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "test_station" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "test_type" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "timestamp" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
          },
          "transaction_date" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
          },
          "waited_value" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

I expect that I have an index with all data in the previous one. The mapping should look like this:

```
{
  "my_index" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "TypeC" : {
        "properties" : {
          "autoid" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "database" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "database_version" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "error_message" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "failure_date" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
          },
          "id_sequence" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "id_test" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "operator" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "part_number" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "read_value" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "serial_number" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "site" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "test_software_version" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "test_station" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "test_type" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "timestamp" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
          },
          "transaction_date" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
          },
          "waited_value" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply reindex both of your old indexes into the new one.
First create your new `typec` (name must be lowercase) index with the expected mapping:

```
PUT typec
{
    "mappings" : {
      "TypeC" : {
        "properties" : {
          "autoid" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "database" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "database_version" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "error_message" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "failure_date" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
          },
          "id_sequence" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "id_test" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "operator" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "part_number" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "read_value" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "serial_number" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "site" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "test_software_version" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "test_station" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "test_type" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "timestamp" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
          },
          "transaction_date" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
          },
          "waited_value" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Then reindex `TypeA` and `TypeB` into `TypeC`(also all lowercase)

```
POST _reindex?wait_for_completion=false
{
  "source": {
    "index": "typea,typeb"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "typec"
  }
}
```

This command will return immediately and give you a task id that you can then use with the following command, to monitor the progress of the reindex:

```
GET _tasks/<task_id>
```